# uwp properties await showing wierd behaviour

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp, async-await, uwp-xaml

In my UWP app I have 2 properties and both are bound to the UI. it all works just fine, until I try to delay addition to one of those properties with Task.Delay.

**Expectation** : Videos collection property should keep getting items without any delay, and Current property should get each item after some delay.

**Problem** : when I try to delay both properties get delayed because after 1st run of loop the delay actually delays the execution of whole loop, but I only want to delay one line of code.

**here is my code**

```
foreach (var file in VideoFiles)
{
    var props = await file.Properties.GetVideoPropertiesAsync();
    var dur = props.Duration;
    var myviews = await DbHelper.GetMyViews(file.Path);
    var vv = new Video
    {
    MyVideoFile = file,
    Views = myviews,
    Duration = $"{dur.Hours.ToString()} : {dur.Minutes.ToString()} : {dur.Seconds.ToString()}",
    Display = await FileHelper.GetDisplay(file),
    };
    Videos.Add(vv);// this line should be execute without any delay

    await Task.Delay(3000);//if I comment this delay line of code then both properties keep getting filled without any delay, which is not what I want

    Current = vv; // this line should be executed after delay
}
```

**UPDATE**

Actually "Videos" is a collection of Video objects which I am displaying on a GridView on the UI so I need to add them without delay.
But Current is an object bound to header on my page, which I need to change after every 3 seconds, after every 3 seconds the header should pick up data from next GridView Item and display it, that is why I need the delay only when updating "Current" property.

Comment: You cannot handle this in a single loop. Fill the collection and use a timer to select the next item

Comment: can you please provide some code on how to use the timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `DispatcherTimer` to set the `Current` property outside of your for loop then. Something like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    int currentIndex = 0;
    timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
    {
        //this code will run every 3 seconds...
        if (Videos.Count > currentIndex)
        {
            Current = Videos[currentIndex++];
        }
    };
    timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: can you please show how I should use this timer in context with the loop? I mean should I just start the timer.Start() function just before the loop starts?

Comment: Yes, it will then check the Videos collection every 3 seconds.